# How can I make Google News output JSON?

Tags: xml, json, rss, google-api

I tried using Google's feed to JSON converter like this: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Foutput%3Drss%26num%3D8

The only problem is that only a maximum of 4 results can be returned. If I go directly to http://news.google.com/news?output=rss&num=8, then there are 8 results. But if I convert it to JSON, there's only 4.

Is there another method of getting Google News results in the JSON format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&num=8` should be part of the load request, not url encoded.

Like this...

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=8&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Foutput%3Drss

Answer (score 3):

you can use  rsz parameter

rsz=4

This argument supplies an integer from 1–8 indicating the number of results to return per page. e.g.

```
 $url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&rsz=8&q=Tarun%20Gupta";
```

Comment: This link has article explaning pagination (just add `&start=8` to skip first 8 results) http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1581074&seqNum=3