# Use jQuery to read a JSON Google news feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, rss

I'm using [this jQuery plugin](http://soyrex.com/articles/jquery-ajax-rss-widget) **([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/22/))** to read Google news rss feed. It requires converting the feed to json format. Then I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151734/how-can-i-make-google-news-output-json) that shows a Google feed in JSON format without the help of Yahoo Pipe:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Foutput%3Drss%26num%3D8
```

I tried the plugin's method to parse the JSON Google feed but failed. Can anyone show me the correct way to read that feed?

My attempt:

```
<script>
$('#rssdata').ready(function()
{
    var pipe_url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=8&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Foutput%3Drss';
    $.getJSON(pipe_url,function(data)
    {
        $(data.feed.entries).each(function(index,entry)
        {

            var item_html = '<li><a target="_blank" href="'+entry.link+'">'+entry.title+'</a></li>';
            $('#rssdata ul.rss-items').append(item_html);
        });
        $('#rssdata div.loading').fadeOut();
        $('#rssdata ul.rss-items').slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

Google News Feed:

```
{"responseData": {"feed":{"feedUrl":"http://news.google.com/news?output\u003drss\u0026num\u003d8","title":"Top Stories - Google News","link":"http://news.google.com/news?pz\u003d1\u0026amp;ned\u003dus\u0026amp;hl\u003den\u0026amp;num\u003d8","author":"","description":"Google News","type":"rss20","entries":[{"title":"Malaysia Airlines loses contact with plane en route to Beijing with 239 aboard - CBS News","link":"http://....
```

Comment: This is great. I want to get the news feed from google which is related to one company lets say as Microsoft. How to get only news feed related to only Microsoft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working because of the **[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)**.

One possible solution is to use `JSONP` which is supported by Google News Feed API.

So you can do:

```
$('#rssdata').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=8&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Foutput%3Drss',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.feed.entries);
            $(data.responseData.feed.entries).each(function (index, entry) {
                var item_html = '<li><a target="_blank" href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>';
                $('#rssdata ul.rss-items').append(item_html);
            });
            $('#rssdata div.loading').fadeOut();
            $('#rssdata ul.rss-items').slideDown();
        },
        error: function () {}

    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/23/)**

Comment: While this is a perfect solution, the google feeds api looks to be deprecated (https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) :(

Comment: it says "This API is no longer available." :-(